# Fullcalendar dayClick return wrong date

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get the date of the clicked day on the calendar by using the function `dayClick`, I've used this for get the the date as object:

```
console.log(date.year());
console.log(date.month());
console.log(date.day());
var startDate = new Date(date.year(), date.month(), date.day(), 0, 0, 0);
```

so in this example I've clicked on `August 6 2016` but in the output I get:

```
2016 - 7 - 6
```

but should be:

```
2016 - 8 - 6
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the JS `Date` object and moment.js objects return the month number starting from zero, not one.

So January is `0` and December is `11`.

In any case you should not work with the date this way, use `moment.js` bundled with fullCalendar.

If it doesn't suit you, just use this to convert to JS Date object:

```
date.toDate();
```

This works because date is a moment.js object.

Comment: okay for the month, but for the day? How can I get the number of the day clicked?

Comment: date.toDate() returns the complete Date object with the year, month and day, you do not need to construct it using six arguments as you are doing now.